# VB.NET Loop MySQLCommand Stuck on ExecuteNonQuery()

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to save data to MySQL table data but stuck at looping, If I am not using looping, no problem occurs. But on looping. The ExecuteNonQuery always stuck and trigger fatal error on command

This is my code

```
Dim X As Integer
        Dim stMp As String
        Dim connTmp As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(ConnString)
        connTmp.Open()
        stMp = ""
        For X = 0 To GridView3.RowCount - 1
            Select Case GridView3.GetRowCellValue(X, "col6").ToString
                Case "M01"  'customer
                    stMp = "UPDATE tbuser SET fcust_a=" & Convert.ToInt32(GridView3.GetRowCellValue(X, "col2")) & ",fcust_e=" & Convert.ToInt32(GridView3.GetRowCellValue(X, "col3")) & ",fcust_d=" & Convert.ToInt32(GridView3.GetRowCellValue(X, "col4")) & ",fcust_v=" & Convert.ToInt32(GridView3.GetRowCellValue(X, "col5")) & " WHERE fuser='" & sUser & "'"
                Case "M02"  'supplier
                    stMp = "UPDATE tbuser SET fsupp_a=" & Convert.ToInt32(GridView3.GetRowCellValue(X, "col2")) & ",fsupp_e=" & Convert.ToInt32(GridView3.GetRowCellValue(X, "col3")) & ",fsupp_d=" & Convert.ToInt32(GridView3.GetRowCellValue(X, "col4")) & ",fsupp_v=" & Convert.ToInt32(GridView3.GetRowCellValue(X, "col5")) & " WHERE fuser='" & sUser & "'"
                Case "M03"  'salesman
                    stMp = "UPDATE tbuser SET fsales_a=" & Convert.ToInt32(GridView3.GetRowCellValue(X, "col2")) & ",fsales_e=" & Convert.ToInt32(GridView3.GetRowCellValue(X, "col3")) & ",fsales_d=" & Convert.ToInt32(GridView3.GetRowCellValue(X, "col4")) & ",fsales_v=" & Convert.ToInt32(GridView3.GetRowCellValue(X, "col5")) & " WHERE fuser='" & sUser & "'"
                ...
...

                Case "T05"
                    stMp = "UPDATE tbuser SET finv_a=" & Convert.ToInt32(GridView3.GetRowCellValue(X, "col2")) & ",finv_e=" & Convert.ToInt32(GridView3.GetRowCellValue(X, "col3")) & ",finv_d=" & Convert.ToInt32(GridView3.GetRowCellValue(X, "col4")) & ",finv_v=" & Convert.ToInt32(GridView3.GetRowCellValue(X, "col5")) & " WHERE fuser='" & sUser & "'"
                Case "T06"
                    stMp = "UPDATE tbuser SET fbyrj_a=" & Convert.ToInt32(GridView3.GetRowCellValue(X, "col2")) & ",fbyrj_e=" & Convert.ToInt32(GridView3.GetRowCellValue(X, "col3")) & ",fbyrj_d=" & Convert.ToInt32(GridView3.GetRowCellValue(X, "col4")) & ",fbyrj_v=" & Convert.ToInt32(GridView3.GetRowCellValue(X, "col5")) & " WHERE fuser='" & sUser & "'"
                Case "T07"
                    stMp = "UPDATE tbuser SET fbyrb_a=" & Convert.ToInt32(GridView3.GetRowCellValue(X, "col2")) & ",fbyrb_e=" & Convert.ToInt32(GridView3.GetRowCellValue(X, "col3")) & ",fbyrb_d=" & Convert.ToInt32(GridView3.GetRowCellValue(X, "col4")) & ",fbyrb_v=" & Convert.ToInt32(GridView3.GetRowCellValue(X, "col5")) & " WHERE fuser='" & sUser & "'"
            End Select

            Try
                If stMp.Length > 0 Then
                    Using connt1 As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(ConnString)
                        connt1.Open()
                        Using mysqlcmd As MySqlCommand = connt1.CreateCommand()
                            mysqlcmd.CommandText = stMp
                            mysqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        End Using
                        connt1.Close()
                    End Using
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(Me, ex.Message)
            End Try

        Next X

        connTmp.Close()
```

I don't know how to fix this

Please help

Revised Code #2

```
Dim X As Integer
        Dim stMp As String
        Dim connTmp As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(ConnString)
        connTmp.Open()
        stMp = ""
        For X = 0 To GridView3.RowCount - 1
            Select Case GridView3.GetRowCellValue(X, "col6").ToString
                Case "M01"  'customer
                    stMp = "UPDATE tbuser SET fcust_a=@value_a,fcust_e=@value_e,fcust_d=@value_d,fcust_v=@value_v WHERE fuser=@userid"
                Case "M02"  'supplier
                    stMp = "UPDATE tbuser SET fsupp_a=@value_a,fsupp_e=@value_e,fsupp_d=@value_d,fsupp_v=@value_v WHERE fuser=@userid"
                Case "M03"  'salesman
...            
...
End Select

            Try
                If stMp.Length > 0 Then
                    Using connt1 As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(ConnString)
                        connt1.Open()
                        Using mysqlcmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(stMp, connt1)
                            With mysqlcmd.Parameters
                                .Add("@value_a", CInt(GridView3.GetRowCellValue(X, "col2")))
                                .Add("@value_e", CInt(GridView3.GetRowCellValue(X, "col3")))
                                .Add("@value_d", CInt(GridView3.GetRowCellValue(X, "col4")))
                                .Add("@value_v", CInt(GridView3.GetRowCellValue(X, "col5")))
                                .Add("@userid", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, UserID)

                            End With

                            mysqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        End Using
                        connt1.Close()
                    End Using
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(Me, ex.InnerException.Message.ToString)
            End Try

        Next X

        connTmp.Close()
```

And the error give new message :

```
Fatal Error encountered attempting to read the resultset
```

I am really dizzy with this.

Comment: That is terrible for a number of reasons, not least being the fact that you tell us that there's an error but not what it is, so we have no idea what we're looking for. You should make significant changes to that code though. Firstly, don't save the data in a loop at all. Populate a `DataTable` with the data and save the lot with a single call to `Update` on a `MySqlDataAdapter`. That will require you to learn how to use parameters, which is what you should be doing anyway. Read [this](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html) for more.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, nice of you for prompt reply, ..and correct yes. I need to learn how to use parameters, ..this is because I was using VB6 for so long, and recently migrate to VB.NET. many things change. After I correct the codes, I will submit working codes

Comment: You could and should use parameters in VB6 too.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i changed the code using parameters from tutorial link you gave me, something new insight for me using this parameters. But now I stumbled into new problem, please advise

Comment: @jmcilhinney if i try to put `mysqlcmd.commandtimeout=86400` before `executenonquery()`, , it will show error : `lock wait time out exceeded, try to restart transaction` ,this really killing me

Comment: Should really start a new question for the new problem, I think your problem now is you’ve got two open connections happening in there now

Comment: You also are still calling `ExecuteNonQuery` in a loop, which you ought not to do. Like I said, populate a `DataTable` with all the data and save the lot with a single call to `Update` on a data adapter. You will need to set the `UpdateCommand` of that adapter and that is where you command with parameters will go. In fact, if you're using a `GridView`, you can probably bind a `DataTable` to it in the first place, although I don't use Web Forms so I'm not sure.

Comment: @jmcilhinney ,i am using winforms and the grid comes from DevExpress Winforms., I understand your last explanation about executenonquery in loop not necessary, using datatable as single update. But I am still looking how to do that in VB.NET, any references ? sorry for bothering you

Comment: @Hursey, is that so ? let me take a look... basically things like that will work very well in VB6, but in VB.NET, things like this won't work anymore.. really exhausted crack this one

Comment: If you're using WinForms then you should almost certainly be using a data adapter to populate a `DataTable` and binding that to your grid. Any changes made in the grid are then automatically pushed to the `DataTable` and you can use the same data adapter to save the changes back to the database. You can probably even use a command builder and not have to create the command or parameters yourself. Any ADO.NET tutorial will cover that so you don't need us to provide references.

Comment: @jmcilhinney make sense from your explanation,  already populate `datatable` when view the table, Now need to find out way to update the changes back to database